# Why is iOS 13 dropping my layout constraint changes?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios13, xcode11

I've got a table view whose cells are configured with autolayout constraints to handle a couple of slightly different layouts depending on their contents. I make the changes by setting the `active` property on the constraints that I want to activate or deactivate. This works fine until I put the app into the background and return to it. When I do this, it looks like my changes are lost and the cells' layout constraints return to the state they originally had in their nib file.

This only occurs when running on iOS 13 with a build from Xcode 11. If I run on iOS 12 with a build from Xcode 10.3 or Xcode 11 I do not see this issue. If I run on iOS 13 with a build from Xcode 10.3 I do not see this issue.

I've tried putting a symbolic breakpoint at `-[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]` but it does not get hit when putting the app into the background or returning it to the foreground.

Has anybody else run into an issue like this? Any hints? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Small project demonstrating this issue is at https://github.com/cooksey/CellLayout

Launch the app, and it should show a table view with a label next to an image. Leave app for home screen, then return to app, and the label now overlaps the image.

Comment: I haven't seen this, but if you can put together a [mcve] I'll take a look at it.

Comment: "This works fine until I put the app into the background and return to it. When I do this, it looks like my changes are lost" Could it be that your app terminates in the background and relaunches when you return to it?

Comment: No, the debugger stays attached across the background-foreground changes. That's also how I've verified that `-[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]` is not being called.

Comment: Well, show us how to experience this behavior then.

Comment: I've added a minimal example program that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the Cell *xib* you unchecked the Installed checkbox for image-aligned label constraint. But that is the very constraint you are wishing would remain activated.

(However, that's just symptomatic. The *real* issue is that your goal is to swap constraints in and out, and you are doing it wrong. You are attempting to do that by starting with *both* sets of constraints in the *xib* file. No. You start with *one* set in the *xib* file and create the other set in code. Keep strong references to both sets. Now swapping them in and out is trivial. Note: during the swap, always remove before adding, or you'll get a conflict.)

Comment: That is intentional. The code in `Cell.m` enables that constraint and disables the `|-12-[label]` constraint. The problem I am running into is that these constraint activation changes are not persistent when leaving and returning to the app.

Comment: Try what I am implying. Check Installed. Run the app. All will be well.

Comment: When I do that, I get conflicting constraint warnings in Interface Builder and in the console log. The behavior looks correct, but when the system is warning me about unsatisfiable conflicting constraints, I don't trust that it will always behave correctly.

Comment: Of course it complains about conflicting constraints. They are conflicting! But the app is fine because the first thing you do as we launch is remove one of them. You can double-check that in the View Debugger but I assure you it works fine. I believe I've answered the question: you did a wrong thing by unchecking Installed. That's not what that checkbox is for.

Comment: Of course the _real_ issue is that this is an x-y problem. Your goal is to swap constraints in and out, which is fine, but having _both_ of them in the _xib_ from the outset is not how you do that. Your attempt to do that was doomed from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I changed the approach from having two constraints activating/deactivating one of them to maintain  just one constraint and updating the constant value to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: My problem with doing this is that I was trying to produce two different layouts. Like, one situation has a button to the side of the text, and the other (large dynamic font size) has the button below the text. Just changing constants won't produce that behavior.